# Laravel match string to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to match values from a user's input (`$index`) to an existing array (`$ppeWorn`). A user can select more than one option. When I try to find out if there are keys of the user's input that match the `$ppeWorn` array, I get only the first item selected.

The value of `dd($indexArray)` is:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]
```

My code is as follows:

```
case 7:
                        $index = ($parts[6]) ;

                        $ppeWorn = [
                            'None',
                            'Gloves',
                            'Fabric mask',
                            'Surgical/Medical mask',
                            'N95 mask (or equivalent)',
                            'Face shield or goggles/protective glasses',
                            'Disposable gown',
                            'Waterproof apron',
                        ];

                        $indexArray = explode(',', $index ) ;
                        dd($indexArray); 
                                                              
                            foreach($indexArray as $value) {

                                if ($ppeWorn[$value]) {

                                    $session["ppes"] = $ppeWorn[$value];
        
                                    $this->setSession($session);
        
                                    dd($session);
        
                                    $response = $this->sessionOpeningTag . "Have you received IPC training?\n1. Yes\n2. No";
                                
                                } else {

                                    $response = $this->sessionClosingTag . "You have entered an invalid answer";
        
                                    $this->deleteSession($session);
        
                                }  
                                 
                            }
                        
                        break;
```

Comment: You need to go get some advice on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ this code is not good - your data structure are particularly inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

So your `$input` is an array, but it's first element is `"1,2"`.
So as my understanding of your question and code (please update the code, provide only useful stuffs), you want to iterate over `$index` and match the values with switch-case.

To do this you may try:

```php
$indexArray = explode(',', $index[0]; // cause $index[0] has a string which has 
                                      // some comma separated value

foreach($indexArray as $value) {
    ... ... ...
    // Do your stuffs here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check exists values from a users `input($index)` to an existing `array($ppeWorn)`. By using this way `___`

```
$checkValue = array_key_exists($users_input,$ppeWorn);
echo $checkValue;
```

> returns true if the key exists in `$ppeWorn`;